# how to get the column output in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, html-table, output

This question is updated 2020-09-15

I've been on this project for a friend like forever now and really need some help
to get this last part working.

I have made a few tables in HTML. Some of the tables (1-3) will add the sum of the rows. Table 2 will also calculate the division between row 1 and row 2, and output it on row 3.
The last two tables are mainly calculations from the input in table 1-3 (and the first row in table 4).

The calculations for the rows works (apart from the first row in table 4, where there should be no sum).

Also, the calculations for the columns work fine... As long as I console log it. When I try to output it in the DOM, Only the first cell in row 3 (table 2) will get a value. This value will be the last inputted value. I have set a default value on row 2 (table 2) to 1, to avoid errors by dividing by 0.

I have tried to find a way to iterate through the columns so that the output would be correct, but with no luck.

Thank you very much for your time.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- FORM 1 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 0</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 1</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 2 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 2</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 3</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 4</th>
              <td>
                <div class="col">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="col">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="col">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="col">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="col">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 3 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 5</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 6</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 4 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 7</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 8</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row8 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row8 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row8 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row8 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 9</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row9 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row9 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row9 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row9 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 10</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row10 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row10 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row10 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row10 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 5 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 11</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row11 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row11 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row11 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row11 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 12</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row12 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row12 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row12 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row12 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 13</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row13 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row13 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row13 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row13 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 14</th>
              <td>
                <div class="row14 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row14 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row14 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="row14 output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 15</th>
              <td>
                <div class="c output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="c output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="c output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="c output">0</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="sum output">0</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
/* 
The goal is to create something tha reminds of an excel spreadsheet,
but with predetermined formulas. The user will only be able to change
the values in the inputs. The rest is simply outputs depending on
those inputs.
For example should row 4 be the products of row 2/ row 3, and row 8
should be the input value -1.
*/
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
Current Problems:
1) Row 7 adds a 5th column. There should not be a sum at the end of
that row.

2) Output for the rows works fine, but for the columns I only get
the correct answer in the console.log, not in the innerHTML.
*/
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

forms.forEach((tableElement) => {
  tableElement.onchange = editSheet;
});

function editSheet() {
  const allrows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

  const DEFAULT_ONE = 1;

  allrows.forEach((i, ix) => {
    rowTotal = 0;
    colTotal = 0;
    row8 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < allrows[ix].getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
      /* Row Total */
      rowTotal =
        rowTotal + Number(allrows[ix].getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value);

      /* Column Total */
      colTotal =
        Number(allrows[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value) /
          Number(allrows[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value) ||
        DEFAULT_ONE;
      console.log(colTotal.toFixed(2));

      /* Row 8 */
      //  row8 = Number(allrows[7].getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value) - 1;
      //  console.log(row8);

      allrows[ix].querySelector(".sum").innerHTML = rowTotal;
      allrows[4].querySelector(".col").innerHTML = colTotal.toFixed(2);
      //  allrows[8].querySelector(".row8").innerHTML = row8;
    }
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/battleaxe/z1tymej2/1/

Comment: Do you want to get the values ​​for an entire column after a change?

Comment: Yeah, like in column1 row 4 = column 1 row 2 / column 1 row 3.... column 2 row 4 = column 2 row 2 / column 2 row 3... and so on. Straight down, column by column.

Comment: Got it. I will present an answer

Comment: Do you need the values ​​only from the inputs or also the "sum" columns?

Comment: I will be needing even the "sum" columns. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The function below obtains all column values ​​and places them in the variable `allValues`

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

forms.forEach((element) => {
  element.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('change', editSheet)
});

function editSheet(event) {
  let cols, rows, col
  
  // Get column number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  for(let i in (rows = this.children)) {
    for(let b in (cols = rows[i].children)) {
      if(cols[b] == event.target.parentElement) {
        col = b // column value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      }
    }
  }
  // end get column number
  
  // Get all values by column number
  let columns = document.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-of-type(${col})`)
  let allValues = []
  columns.forEach(cols => {
    let number, inpt
    if(inpt = cols.querySelector('input')) {
        number = inpt.value
      allValues.push(number)
    } else if(inpt = cols.querySelector('div')) {
      allValues.push(inpt.innerText)
    }
  })
  // end
  
  // result
  console.log(allValues)
  
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  height: min-content;
  width: max-content;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(56, 192, 255), rgb(235, 235, 255));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 13px;
}
tr {
  height: 30px;
}
input {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
th {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.sum,
.col,
.output {
  background: rgb(206, 206, 206);
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
hr {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- FORM 1 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 0</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 1</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 2 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 2</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 3</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 4</th>
              <td><div class="col">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="col">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="col">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="col">0</div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 3 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 5</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 6</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 4 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 7</th>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" value="0" /></td>
              <td><div class="sum output"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 8</th>
              <td><div class="row8 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row8 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row8 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row8 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 9</th>
              <td><div class="row9 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row9 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row9 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row9 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 10</th>
              <td><div class="row10 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row10 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row10 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row10 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output"></div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!-- FORM 5 -->
      <form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 11</th>
              <td><div class="row11 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row11 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row11 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row11 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 12</th>
              <td><div class="row12 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row12 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row12 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row12 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 13</th>
              <td><div class="row13 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row13 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row13 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row13 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 14</th>
              <td><div class="row14 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row14 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row14 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="row14 output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Row 15</th>
              <td><div class="c output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="c output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="c output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="c output">0</div></td>
              <td><div class="sum output">0</div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First I looked for the column number (the number of the element `td` child of `tr`) and with that value I was able to obtain the values ​​of all columns with the second loop (I commented that part)

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wLjphzc1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look at this in about 2 hours. I just skimmed it, and I can't really see how I should handle the output to the page (DOM). Maybe it'll come clear when I take a closer look, but maybe you have a clue to share?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. What you asked for in the comments is to get all the values ​​of a column that was modified. I don't know what your code is for

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. I will try again. If you run my initial code, you will see that the end column with the rows with input, will sum the inputs. In the second form (row 3-5), there is the same thing, but it is also supposed to output a calculation for the columns in row 5.I'm having the same problem with row 8, so I guess it will continue like that. In the code I have with my question, things works fine when I console log it, but I can't get it right when I try to use innerHTML. Your way also looks great (I jus haven't had enough time today to make it work). Thanks for help

Comment: Simply put, like an excel sheet :)

Comment: Remove the rows and columns that have a div and add an input instead of them with the `disabled` attribute, then use my code to get the complete column and apply the necessary mathematical operations. :)

Comment: Ah, awsome! Will do. Thanks again Aks :)